# Correct/correctly

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, adverbs

> Congratulations for spelling all your words correct.

I would use “correctly” rather than “correct”.

Can anyone explain why they use an adjective (correct) instead of an adverb (correctly) in this sentence? It doesn’t sound right to me.

Comment: What's the source of the given sentence?

Comment: My son’s primary school teacher

Comment: "correctly" is the correct word. But it's very common in casual conversation to use adjectives as adverbs.

Comment: I don't think much of the teacher's English!